# How to prevent selected long string values from getting truncated in the react-select control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, controls, react-select

I'm using `react-select` `Creatable` component. Whenever I select long value, it gets truncated and 3 dots get added at the end of the selected value. Is there any way to disable this truncation? I'd like to see entire selected values.

[image]

If it's any help, here's my code

```
 <ReactCreatableSelect
            disabled={isDisabled}
            filterOption={createFilter({ ignoreAccents: false })}
            options={options}
            onChange={this.onNewSelectChange}
            onCreateOption={this.onCreateOption}
            components={{ MenuList }}
            isMulti={this.isMulitpleChoice()}
            value={((!Array.isArray(value) ? [value] : value) as Array<any>).map(x => ({ label: x, value: x }))}
            isClearable={true}
            isSearchable={true}
            isLoading={loading}

          />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Dairylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951076/dairylee), I've found the right solution for this

```
const ReactSelectStyles = () => ({
  multiValueLabel: (styles: any) => ({
    ...styles,
    whiteSpace: "normal",
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to override the styles for the `MultiValueLabel` and remove the current `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` styles that are applied by default.

```
const ReactSelectStyles = () => ({
  multiValueLabel: styles => ({
    ...styles,
    overflow: auto,
    text-overflow: ""
  }),
})

<ReactCreatableSelect 
  ...
  styles={ReactSelectStyles()}
/>
```

---

*I would recommend not doing this as it's done this way for a reason. It currently only truncates the text when it's too large to fit inside the `Select` box.*